# How do I calculate for the change in value?

Tags: arithmetic, average

Question:
"In a village the average age of n people is 42 years. But after the verification it was found that the age of a person had been considered 20 years less than the actual age , so the new average, after the correction, increased by 1. The value of n is:"

I am particularly finding it difficult to deal with increase on both side. Had this been the original value things would have been much easier. What exactly am I missing. Some help about the same will be most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum of everyone's age in the village before the correction in $42n$. After the correction, the sum is now $42n+20$. The question states that that is equal to $43n$.

$$42n+20=43n \Rightarrow n=20.$$